# How to position images in OSF (Open Science Framework)?

Tags: image, position, wiki

I aim to position an image in OSF wiki pages.

My question is how to position images in OSF (Open Science Framework).

Here is my current code to left align the image:

```
![OutputHierarchy](https://osf.io/745ch/download =200x200)
```